# MockitoJUnit Test unable to instantiate mocked object

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to unit test my Class using *MockitoJUnitRunner.class*

Here's the code snippet from my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AHCLIManagerTest {

    @Mock
    RObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Mock
    AHCLIUpdateCommand ahcliUpdateCommandMock;

    @InjectMocks
    AHCLIManager underTest;
```

And in my main class, I have :

```
@Service
public class AHCLIManager implements ProductionUpdateManager {

    @Autowired
    private RObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private AHCLIUpdateCommand ahcliUpdateCommand;
```

When I try to read an object from a JSON string using the object mapper, as follows, I get a NullPointerException

```
   JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(requestJSON);
```

I tried to use ReflectionTestUtils to initialize the objectMapper from the Test class as below, and the test case passed

```
 ReflectionTestUtils.setField(underTest, "objectMapper", new RObjectMapper());
```

**EDIT:**

Also, I'm using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` as follows:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

I'm not sure why the the Mock injection isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure that it fails on the `objectMapper.readTree`? Or does it fail on the line that uses the `rootNode`? The default response to a method is to return `null` if you haven't specified anything. If you are using a newly instantiated object (like you do with the `ReflectionTestUtils` if will of course succeed as you are injecting a full instance instead of a mock.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for downvoting me.  When I answered this question 6 hours ago (5 minutes after it was posted), the OP did _not_ show any evidence that `initMocks()` was being called, hence my answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment you don't need that due to the use of the runner, the `initMocks` is only needed if you cannot use the runner.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes, the code fails at the line that uses rootNode, but this is definitely happening because objectMapper is not instantiated, because when I use ReflectionTestUtils, it is able to read the json.

Comment: No it isn't... You are using a mock and as I stated the default of the mock is to return `null` when a method is invoked. If you don't want this you need to tell the mock what to return. DO you actually understand what a mock is?

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry I wasn't thinking straight. Of course, you're right! Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have corresponding setters in your `AHCLIManager`?

What `@InjectMocks` does, if I remember correctly, is simply injecting through setters with matching type of mock object declared by `@Mock`.  Mockito is not doing anything base on `@Autowired`.

(It have nothing to do with using `MockitoJUnitRunner` or calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` anyway)

Another possibility is that you may have created the instance of  `AHCLIManager` in your setup method.  Mockito is going to instantiate the `AHCLIManager` for you if you have annotated it with `@InjectMocks`

Answer (score 0):

You're using different strategies for creating the mocks. You should either use the `MockitoJUnitRunner` or the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` method.